# WCF Namespaces in Contract/Behaviour Attribute Classes

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, namespaces, wsdl

In WCF Services every `Attribute Class` has a Property called `Namespace`

- ServiceContractAttribute Class
- DataContractAttribute Class
- ServiceBehaviorAttribute Class

you can assign those attributes namespaces like the following:

```
[ServiceContract(Name="Webservice", Namespace = "https://myDomain.com/ext/MyWebApplication")]
    public interface IWebservice
    {
    ...
    }
```

I know this is used for example to get rid of the default `targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/"` in the WSDL File. What am I supposed to set the Namespaces to though?
I want to host my WCF Service called *Webservice* inside my ASP.NET Web Application at `https://myWebApplication/ext/Webservice.svc`.
I've seen other WSDL Files have `targetNamespaces` like `http://com.company.websvc/webservicename/` which namespace do i have to set at each of the Attribute Classes? And after declaring them "programmatically" do i still have to specify the namespaces in my App.Config file?